# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am receiving the following errors when I am trying to run my script

> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot instantiate class  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable
>   must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;

```
package EDRTermsPackge;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class ContactInformationTesting {

 //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

 @BeforeMethod
 public void beforeMethod() {
  //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
  String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";

  //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);
 }

 @Test
 public void OpenPage_Login() {
  driver.get("http://cp-qa.harriscomputer.com/");
 }
}
```

Comment: @JJWhispers - I believe you should be updating your question with the source code, than posting the code as one of the answers to your own question.I have edited your question to include the source code that you shared (I cleaned up the commented out code)

Answer (score 2):

You should set your path to driver first and then instantiate IEDriver, you can't use `new InternetExplorerDriver();` before `System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);`

In your case you could do something like this (No need for @BeforeMethod to do just this simple property setup):

```
public class ContactInformationTesting {

  //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
  String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";

  //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);

  //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

 @Test
 public void OpenPage_Login() {
  driver.get("http://cp-qa.harriscomputer.com/");
 }
```

Comment: Im getting this error message as a result of the changes

Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Comment: public class ContactInformationTesting   {
 
 //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
 String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";
 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath); //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
 
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
 

  @Test
  public void OpenPage_Login() {


  driver.get("http://cp-qa.harriscomputer.com/");
  }

Answer (score 0):

> String exePath = "\Users\jj85274\Desktop\IEDriverServer.exe";

This line kind of hints as if you are trying to set the `IEDriverServer` binary from a network drive. Is that so ? I am not sure if network paths can be accessed by Java code directly.

I would suggest that instead of trying to add the `IEDriverServer.exe` path in your source code for every test, you might as well include this binary in your `PATH` variable. You can do this on windows by dropping this exe into one of the directories that is listed in the output of the below command

On Windows
`echo %PATH%`

On Non-Windows
`echo $PATH`