# how to remove error "Cannot instantiate class day2practice.day2" in testng class

Tags: selenium, testng

```
package day2practice;       

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.testng.Assert;  
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class day2 {
     ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

     @BeforeMethod
     public void beforeMethod() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Ashok\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);         
          driver.navigate().to("http://live.guru99.com");
     }

     @Test
     public void f() {    
         String actual = driver.getTitle();
         String expected = "THIS IS DEMO SITE";
         Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected, "page title is same");
     }

     @AfterMethod
     public void close() {
         driver.quit();
     }
 }
```

Comment: m getting this error for every testng class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012518/org-testng-testngexception-cannot-instantiate-class)

Answer (score 1):

Don't instantiate `ChromeDriver` class before assigning the path to `chromedriver.exe`. Moved the instantiation code to `beforeMethod`.

try the following code:

```
package day2practice;       

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class day2 {
     ChromeDriver driver;

     @BeforeMethod
     public void beforeMethod() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Ashok\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);         
          driver.navigate().to("http://live.guru99.com");
     }

     @Test
     public void f() {    
         String actual = driver.getTitle();
         String expected = "THIS IS DEMO SITE";
         Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected, "page title is same");
     }

     @AfterMethod
     public void close() {
         driver.quit();
     }
 }
```